# Simplest solution for change the application font to roboto font in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, fonts

How can I change the application font to Roboto ttf, I saw a solutions for changing every TextView, but I want to configure the font in one place in the project and change the font for every TextView, EditText and Spinner.
thanks in advance.

Comment: i encounter with the same issue... Say me please have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder in the assets folder to put your fonts "Assuming Roboto.ttf"

**assets/fonts/Roboto.ttf**

Create the type face and apply it to your textview using

```
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                                      "fonts/Roboto.ttf");
List<TextView> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list,textView_1,textView_2,textView_3);

for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    list.get(i).setTypeface(font);
}
```

You can also use this library for **ROBOTO** fonts

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.elmargomez.typer:typerlib:1.0.0'
}
```

Then:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
   list.get(i).setTypeface(Typer.set(yourContext).getFont(Font.ROBOTO_REGULAR));
}
```

Comment: Here I need to change every TestView in the Layout, looking for more effective way.

Comment: @user1684140 Sorry for that but i tried to make an edit to the code,use the for loop

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `TextView`, customise it and then use `CustomTextView` across your Application.

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        applyCustomFont(context);
    }

    private void applyCustomFont(Context context) {
        Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "roboto-bold.ttf");
        setTypeface(customFont);
    }
}
```

Please refer to [this](https://futurestud.io/blog/custom-fonts-on-android-extending-textview/) link for further information.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem... U still have to create a diff classes if you need diff view element...

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library easiest way. It Also allow you to use different font at the same time;